# How to get token id for solana NFT

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

Is there a solana/web3 function to return the token id of a NFT?

I'm not sure if that's a thing on Solana or if Opensea is adding those.
For example, opensea says [this one](https://opensea.io/assets/solana/31fgM5ZVkDkwwYCWHKXKFWbw2aDXjDpYgj7pjGU46Uhk) is #52

Answer (score 0):

nop, opensea doesn't say this nft is #52. This is taken from name in the metadata and this is not a token id

https://solscan.io/token/31fgM5ZVkDkwwYCWHKXKFWbw2aDXjDpYgj7pjGU46Uhk#metadata

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly want to do with token Id ?

I think what you are looking for is Token Address

If so, then its in the url. or you can look it on sol scan here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing for Solana NFT is the concept of collection https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections